# How to alter the drupal8 user login form inputs and validation?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want hook and write for my account page. so kindly provide me sample example or procedure for writing hook form alter module with info file and module file for drupal8.

Comment: what do u want to alter?before doing that,do u know u can add fields and od many thing on the account with the back-office ? /admin/config/people/accounts/fields

Comment: alter the form name like email address to Email. example user/login page there is username and password but i want to change as username or email address and password. I want sample code of hook.info and hook.module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just copy paste a standard .info to create a module

in your .module add the hook form alter

```
 /**
* callback action on submit (custom method plus bas)
*
* @param $form
* @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
* @param $form_id
*/
  function yourModuleName_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {


if ($form_id == 'user_login_form') {

    //code to modify your form input

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_method';

   //do something similar to create a custom validation handler

}

}

/**
 * @param $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function custom_submit_method(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    //code to modify the submit if needed

 }
```

Comment: Thanks i got the answer. But i used as the modulename_form_user_login_form_alter and i applied the attributes placeholder $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('username or email');. I want more to workout for title change and custom submit. If anything face issue, i will comment. Why u using block_generator_form_alter.

Comment: i have edited the reply , block generator was part of the name i gave to my module

Comment: yes this custom submit function is working fine but how to get the post values in this function. I have used like this ($cuser = $form_state['values']['name']) but it is not working.

Comment: $form_state->getValue('name_of_your_value'))

Comment: I get the value but on using the hook_user_login($cuser, $cpass) just as input (admin, admin) its not logging in. Suggest me no idea in this hooks

Comment: You need to unshift validators to put yours after defaults.